# Postgres Maximum max month for each quarter/year

Tags: postgresql

I have table with columns: PK,Amount,quarter,month,year,program. I would like to create query which help me to select only the max month for each quarter/year for each policy. Example:
[image]

should return something like

[image]

how would I accomplish this using postgres?

Comment: Both tables are same, enter your data as text so the community can help you. By the way what data type is your month column?

Comment: First use a consistent naming scheme for `month`. Then use `to_date()` from here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and then  `data_part(month from ...)` from [Datetime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH max_month AS (
    SELECT
        quarter,
        policy,
        max(to_date(month || ' ' || year, 'month YYYY')) AS max_date
        FROM
            qtr_test
        GROUP BY
            quarter,
            policy) SELECT qtr_test.*
FROM
    qtr_test, max_month
WHERE
    qtr_test.quarter = max_month.quarter
    AND qtr_test.policy = max_month.policy
    AND to_date(month || ' ' || year, 'month YYYY') = max_date
ORDER BY quarter, policy;

 pk | amount | quarter | month | year | program | policy 
----+--------+---------+-------+------+---------+--------
  1 |   2500 | q1      | march | 2022 | A       | p1
  8 |   3000 | q1      | march | 2022 | A       | p2
  5 |   2700 | q2      | july  | 2022 | A       | p2
```

Use `CTE` to find the maximum date for the quarter, policy combination. Then use the quarter, policy and max_date to select the appropriate rows from the table.